# Drawing a Fibonacci Spiral in Inkscape without the Extension?

Tags: inkscape

This tutorial shows how to draw a Fibonacci spiral in Inkscape using an extension.

https://youtu.be/4NXuo8fe7kk

However the extension crashes in my version of Inkscape (1.2-alpha).

Anyone know of a different technique for drawing the spiral?

Comment: Is there a reason ror you to use an alpha version of software? One could be constructed but math will be involved.

Comment: Yes.  The stable version kept crashing on my macbook ... Also the initial dialog could not be closed without forcing the close ...

Comment: So stable version crashes inkscape and unstable version crashes your inkscape?

Comment: The stable Inkscape version crashes and locks in general ... so I switched to the alpha version ... but now the Fibonacci plugin crashes ... :)

Comment: I don't know if this applies to macs, but you could try it. Using the stable releases of Inkscape 1.x, I have found that if you keep the document properties dialog open in Inkscape, it crashes or freezes randomly. Close the dialog.

Comment: Fibonacci spiral is a series of joined circular arcs (quarters of circles). No extension is needed to draw it. The radiuses of the circles are taken from Fibonacci number sequence. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number  I guess you actually want something totally different which also can be built around Fibonacci sequence. - maybe Vogel's model for certain pattern in plants?

Comment: You don't need the extension for this. It's possible using Inkscape's Tiled Clone functionality. [see example](https://imgur.com/tBoZRql).  It's a bit long to do a full tutorial here, but there is [one on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSm8UaMx6zY) that will help you get you started (it's in Italian, but you can still follow the steps).

Comment: @user287001 no it is not. It is often approximated as a series of arcs because that is what you did by hand. You can get far better approximations using properties of beziers.

Comment: @joojaa the questioner has asked a dot pattern which looks like it could be tiled radially outwards from the center and the dot density still stays constant. That's the Vogel's model. Fibonacci spiral is the piecewice circular arc approximation of a certain logarithmic spiral named "the golden spiral". Rectify, If this is false.

Comment: @user287001 ah yes your right, i am wrong. Seems stupid though not to draw a approximation of a golden spiral. Beacuse the alternative is to draw the approximation of a approximation of a golden spiral.

Comment: All - Great tips!!  Thank you!!